# Thread starts after onDestroy

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

i've created a new thread for receiving bluetooth data in background. When I'm closing the application the thread closes correctly. But when I'm changing the activity the thread opens up again.

```
private void receiveDataInBackground() {
Log.d(TAG, "receive Data in Background");
handlerInBackground = new Handler();
handlerInBackground.postDelayed(myRunnableInBackground = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dataReceived=false;
        Log.d(TAG, "in receiveBackground");
        openBT();
         //
            if(dataReceived==true){closeBT();}
            handlerInBackground.postDelayed(this, 60000);
        }
    }, 60000);
}
```

and this is my onDestroy

```
public void onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();
saveArrayList(btDataList, "btDataList");
btAdapter.disable();
Log.d(TAG, "finishing APP");
handlerInBackground.removeCallbacksAndMessages(myRunnableInBackground);
finish();
```

Someone knows that problem or could help me? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Full code could be find on github:
https://github.com/LongDong279/AppGeruest3

Answer (score 0):

use `onPause()`  instead of `onDestroy()`

```
public void onPause(){
     super.onPause();
     saveArrayList(btDataList, "btDataList");
     btAdapter.disable();
     Log.d(TAG, "finishing APP");
     handlerInBackground.removeCallbacksAndMessages(myRunnableInBackground);
}
```

if I do understand you well "changing the activity" means you go to another activity from it. so you may need to call `finish()` after you start the activity.

Comment: thanks, will try it.
Does onPause get called when I minimize the app?

Comment: yes. it's called before onDestroy() .. google image : the activity lifecycle for better understanding.

Comment: alright, thanks.
Problem: my Methods i want to get called in the onDestroy Method.
I could solve my Problem by adding handlerInBackground.removeCallbacks.
BUT! now my app won't close correctly, it still remains in background. How do i get this info? -> Android Studio won't stop debugging

Comment: is your `receiveDataInBackground()` is a part of a separate thread.you can stop this thread only by assigning it to null. try to do that in `onPause`. this will stop it for sure

Comment: Thanks will try this. Problem, is i need this Thread if the app is in background to receive data over bluetooth in background. Or is there another way to handle this? 
Thanks

Comment: I've tried some things and noticed that every thread is closing correctly in the onDestroyed, checked it with the alive method. The problem must be somewhere else

Comment: post your full code. also, check this library 
https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary

Comment: I will share my github folder. Thanks